# VBA Sum column with variable row count

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that I need to sum and store the total as a variable. I have looked on this site and online and tried to adapt my syntax to how I believe it should work but still with no luck.

I was wondering if someone might be able to point out where I am going wrong.

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim Total_TIV As Long

With Sheets("Input")
    RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C18", Range("C18").End(xlDown)))
End With

With Sheets("Input")
    Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum("S18" & ":S" & 18 + RowCount)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just return the row at the bottom of the range.

You only need one with block.

You need to append the ranges with `.` to indicate it belongs to the parent.

The SUM requires a range object not a string.

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Total As Double

With Sheets("Input")
    RowCount = .Range("C18").End(xlDown).Row
    Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("S18:S" & RowCount))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks both for your help. Strangely I'm getting an error 6 overflow on both pieces of code. For extra info the answer I'm trying to get to is 16 billion?

Comment: @Carlos80 see edit.  You will need `Total` to be a Double and make sure the `RowCount` is a Long.

Answer (score 0):

SUM() needs a range *(just like `CountA()`)*:

```
  Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("S18" & ":S" & (18 + RowCount)))
```